(Qt version 5.15.3) This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"
when i run qtcreator like this ./qtcreator, the error come out
enter image description here
and the ubuntu version is 22.04 ,qmake version is 3.1
enter image description here
i have tried many soultions to solve this problem,but it doesn't work ,like apt install some lib or something like export xxx=xxx
the url  (Qt 5.4.1) This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" that i followed, it also doesn't work    someone can help me to solve this problem.

Your links don't work. Please share the debug output after setting the environment variable QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1.
